# I am trying to resize my img to fit right above my navbar so its not so big?

Tags: html, css

So first I am doing freecodecamp and this is my Pen I am working on https://codepen.io/chrisalta94/pen/JwdBEq

As you can see the image and the space around it is too big, how can I reduce the size so it will look better, and if anyone knows how can I make it responsive?

CSS

```
#header-img {
display: flex;
height: 100%;
background:black;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100vh;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: what do you want us to do? please show with picture.

Comment: Sorry it would be something like this https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NRJDWa7MyRE/maxresdefault.jpg where the logo and background is scaled down just above the nav bar

Comment: do `img {height:100px}`  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a height attribute to your  tag.

For example:

```
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/73/fb/7f/73fb7fb7b9cd1833e16bb4fcef17a962.png" 
    alt="Adidas Logo"  height="200">
```

This way you can choose a particular height that works for you.

As for making it responsive, this is usually done by setting several media queries at different widths, that change the design when it breaks down. So this usually includes a lot of experimenting with when the design starts to break down.

Alternatively, what I often find just as effective and much simpler, is using the `orientation: portrait` media query, like so:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  /* CSS that needs to change here */

}
```

This will change the specific CSS on every viewport in portrait orientation. This includes phones and tablets for example, but also desktop browsers windows that are resized to a portrait orientation!

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my problem!

Comment: Glad I could help. As a sidenote, the correct english plural of 'man' and 'woman' is 'men' and 'women'. You might want to correct those, since native english speakers will notice this quickly, and think it unprofessional. Other than that, good looking site ;)